# Angular - Simple CRUD application without NgRx?

Tags: angular, crud, ngrx, state-management

I am currently learning Angular and following the Maximilian Schwarzmüller Udemy course.

I have a simple CRUD application to manage recipes with data saved in a database, and I want to be able to delete, create, and update a recipe by sending an HTTP request, and then update the list of recipes accordingly.

[UI of this application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnCsN.png)

Using just RxJS BehaviorSubject and a service, I currently have this implementation to delete a recipe:

```
export class RecipeDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedRecipe: Recipe;
  
    constructor(
      private recipeService: RecipeService,
      private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router
    ) { }
  
    ngOnInit() {
      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
        const id = params.id;
        this.recipeService.getRecipeById(id).subscribe((recipe) => {
          this.selectedRecipe = recipe;
        });
      });
    }
  
  
    onDeleteRecipe() {
      this.recipeService.deleteRecipe(this.selectedRecipe.id).subscribe({
        next: () => {
          this.router.navigate(['/recipes']);
          this.recipeService.recipesUpdate.next();
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.error('error deleting recipe : ', error);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

```
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
  recipes$: Observable<Recipe[]>;
  isLoading = false;
  errorMessage: string;
  constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initRecipes();
    this.recipeService.recipesUpdate.subscribe(() => this.initRecipes());
  }

  initRecipes() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.recipes$ = this.recipeService.getRecipes().pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        console.error('error retrieving recipes : ', error);
        this.errorMessage = `Error retrieving recipes : ${error.error.error}`;
        return of([]);
      }),
      tap({ complete: () => (this.isLoading = false) })
    );
  }
}
```

```
export class RecipeService {
    API_URL =
      'XXX';
    private recipes: Recipe[] = [];
  
    recipesUpdate: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  
    recipes$ = new BehaviorSubject<Recipe[]>(this.recipes);
  
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
    getRecipes() {
      return this.http.get<Recipe[]>(`${this.API_URL}/recipes.json`)
    }
  
    getRecipeById(id: string) {
      return this.http.get<Recipe>(`${this.API_URL}/recipes/${id}.json`)
    }
  
    addRecipe(recipe: Recipe) {
      return this.http
        .post(`${this.API_URL}/recipes.json`, recipe)
        .subscribe((response) => {
          this.recipesUpdate.next();
        });
    }
  
    updateRecipe(recipe: Recipe) {
      return this.http
        .put(`${this.API_URL}/recipes/${recipe.id}.json`, recipe)
        .subscribe((response) => {
          this.recipesUpdate.next();
        });
    }
  
    deleteRecipe(id: string) {
      return this.http.delete(`${this.API_URL}/recipes/${id}.json`);
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, particularly the way I am updating the list of recipes in the RecipeListComponent using an empty Subject and subscribing to it in the ngOnInit method.

I have read many comments about NgRx and how it is often considered overkill for simple applications (https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/), but I am not sure how to do it without using it.

Furthermore, I don't like the fact that I have to "reload" the recipe list and show the loader after deleting, creating, or updating a recipe. I used React Query with React for this purpose. Is there a way to achieve the same with Angular?

BONUS QUESTION:
Regarding NgRx, in my Angular course, I am almost at the part about NgRx, but I am unsure whether I should follow it or not. Do you think it is worth learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all wanted to commend you on great first question documentation. I also was starting with Maximilian Schwarzmüller.

Using **services** for state management is perfectly fine approach. And overall what you are doing there is fine. I would recommend to investigate imperative vs declarative code (Joshua Morony has decent content on the topic). For example, you can display recipes directly in the template using `async` [pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) avoiding subscription hassle.

What you are describing about loader, this behavior can be mitigated by using optimistic rendering. When user performs CRUD operation you make change on local state simultaneously with remote state, not showing any loader, in case of an error you rollback local state and show user an error.

A detail regarding "recipes$" in RecipeListComponent: when an error occurs in the observable sequence, the catchError operator is triggered, and it handles the error and returns a new observable. In this case, the catchError operator returns an observable of an empty array (of([])). Therefore, the tap operator will not be reached and its side effect, setting isLoading to false, will not occur.

Regarding bonus question: I have started using ngrx 4 month ago, and consider it a great tool. At this point I would argue that if ngrx is overkill than so is angular itself. Once you have enough practice its not harder that services. NGRX forces you to create more transparent and cleaner data flows which can save you a lot of debugging time. Here comes but... but I do believe that ngrx is overkill for someone starting with angular, from learning curve point of view. I would definitely wait until I had solid grasp on Angular itself before adding on more weight.

Hope I didn't miss anything.

**Refactor suggestion**

After looking your code closer I saw some redundant actions. I would suggest refactoring your code. Here is fetching recipes as an example:

When we call get recipes, first of all we push loading true to inform everyone listening that recipes are being loaded. Then we make api call itself. You may notice **take(1)** pipe, its purpose is to automatically unsubscribe after first emission. Depending on backend you are using it may be unnecessary, be still its a good practice to prevent memory leaks.

Also we have **finalize** pipe which will execute when observable completes or errors.

When value is received it is sent through **recipes$**.

```
export class RecipeService {
    API_URL = 'XXX';
    isLoading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    recipes$ = new BehaviorSubject<Recipe[]>([]);
    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getRecipes() {
        this.isLoading$.next(true);
        this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/recipes.json`)
            .pipe(
                take(1),
                finalize(() => this.isLoading$.next(false))),
                catchError((error) => {
                    console.error('error retrieving recipes : ', error);
                    this.errorMessage = `Error retrieving recipes : ${error.error.error}`;
                    return of([]);
                }
            ).subscribe((recipes)=>{
                this.recipes$.next(recipes)
            })
    }
}
```

On initialization of our list component we execute getRecipes() to make backend call.

```
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
    recipes$: Observable<Recipe[]> = this.recipeService.recipes$;
    errorMessage: string;
    constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.recipeService.getRecipes();
    }
}
```

Template would be:

`<app-recipe-item *ngFor="let recipe of recipes$ | async"></app-recipe-item>`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, 

 **you can display recipes directly in the template using `async`  pipe**
 
 I used it in my RecipeList template 
`<app-recipe-item
      *ngFor="let recipe of recipes$ | async"
      [recipe]="recipe"
    ></app-recipe-item>`
Did you talk about another way to do it ?

**A detail regarding "recipes$" in RecipeListComponent:**

Indeed, I see the problem now. I think I can use rxjs 'finalize' to set the loading to false

Comment: About the **optimistic rendering** to avoid using a loader, I tried to use local state, but it did not resolve the synchronization issue with the backend.

For instance, when I delete a Recipe, I can update the RecipeList on the client side. However, if another Recipe is deleted on the backend during that time, I cannot obtain the updated RecipeList without fetching the updated list (and displaying the loader).

Do i miss something about this issue ?

Comment: Yeaah... Regarding your first question, looking more closely I see the mess, I am going to edit my response with a refactor of your code. About second question, do I understand correctly that you want a have a shared database between multiple users and when one of them modifies it, everyone should receive an update? Otherwise I don´t see why it would be deleted on backend.

Comment: I've worked on an application made to manage clients devices for admins. So the front-end wad a basic CRUD of the devices.
And we had cases when a device was edited/deleted by a client or just a new device was added to the park (not via the Admin CRUD).

So fetching updated devices often as possible was providing a better UX (We used react query for that)

But maybe it is a niche case, and for majority of application, we can have the front-end state used and not updated by the backend for each CRUD operation ?

I will look on imperative vs declarative code thanks !

Comment: It completely depends on expected user . If users have access only to their own data, I wouldn´t bother preparing for a case where user makes modifications on two devices simultaneously. If he wants to get new data he should update the page. In case you do need live updates, for cases where multiple users are working on same data, you can create a cron function that would trigger in the background once every x minutes, or use something like firebase onSnapshot() that feeds you live updates. Please note, any of this does not affect optimistic rendering.

Comment: With optimistic rendering you still have to make API calls on each CRUD operation from same device. The point is to render modified data immediately, without waiting for server response thus avoiding loading spinners. In case server errors out you rollback that crud operation and show error message to the user.